# How do you program an iOS app to respond to commands from a Bluetooth keyboard that aren't part of the iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-keyboard

Like scrolling in a list Or clicking the return button on the keyboard to click an "ok" Button. I'v searched the internet but I could only find  results for questions about connecting Bluetooth keyboards.

Comment: Classic Bluetooth is not accessible directly from within apps; users must connect at the OS level (via Preferences>Bluetooth). Apps can only communicate with BTLE devices. Is this a BTLE device?

Comment: No I was thinking just a normal keyboard connected to the device. to control the app with the keys for example on the iPad in the swift playground app you can do things like (Command + ]) to move that row one tab no mater where the curser is but you can't do that in any other app that I know so I was wondering if you could do that with code for you're own apps. Ps Sorry I didn't ask my question very well.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the fact that iOS doesn't expose the events quite the way OS X does. It's actually similar, but it looks like they've made a couple of pieces private. https://nacho4d-nacho4d.blogspot.com/2012/01/catching-keyboard-events-in-ios.html?m=1